# PDO SQLite difficulties

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Could someone please tell me what is wrong with my code.  When I try to use the function, I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object in ...
```

Using:

```
if (!$IDq) { print_r($dbh->errorInfo()); }
```

gives me:
file is encrypted or is not a database

I have been messing with it for ages but can't seem to get it to work.

```
function user_registered($user_id){
$dbh = new PDO("sqlite:datastore/userids.db");
$IDq = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM users_identify WHERE identifier = '$user_id'");
$IDq->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$IDf = $IDq->fetch();
if($IDf['id']){
return $IDf['id'];
}else{
return 0;
}
}
```

Thanks.

EDIT: Ah, thanks for your help. I found the problem, it was that I was using an sqlite 2 database when I needed an sqlite 3 database.

Comment: Add this after your `query`: `if (!$IDq) { print_r($dbh->errorInfo()); }`

Comment: @calummc - it's better to add your own answer, rather than to edit your question to add it there. You can award yourself the tick, but don't forget to +1 on anyone you found helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to do that, but SO said something about not being able to answer your own question with less than 100 rep. within 7 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was that I was using an sqlite 2 database when I needed an sqlite 3 database. I guess that was the source of the 'file is encrypted or is not a database' message.

```
var_dump($dbh->errorInfo());
```

Helped my find the source of the problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

By default, PDO will not return a PDOStatement from PDO::query() if the query failed.  Instead, `$IDq` would be set to `false`, which is a non-object.

Something is wrong with your query or PDO object, and you can check it by:

```
var_dump($dbh->errorInfo());
```

Also, PHP advises that if you are going to use PDO::query() that you protect your query this way:

```
$IDq = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM users_identify WHERE identifier = " . $dbh->quote($user_id));
```

Comment: thanks, I got: file is encrypted or is not a database.  I can open userids.db with phpLiteAdmin...

Comment: Where is it documented that PDO::query() is not recommended?

Comment: @thetaiko I may be mistaken about PDO::query(), but...
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php
"If you are using this function to build SQL statements, you are strongly recommended to use PDO::prepare() to prepare SQL statements with bound parameters instead of using PDO::quote() to interpolate user input into an SQL statement. Prepared statements with bound parameters are not only more portable, more convenient, immune to SQL injection, but are often much faster to execute than interpolated queries, as both the server and client side can cache a compiled form of the query."

Comment: @Deltik - PHP advises preparing and then executing queries if you're passing in data.  But there is no recommendation against using `->query`, per se.  I'm being contentious now, though, which I apologize for.  I was genuinely curious if there was some sort of performance implication or security implication outside the obvious in the documentation that I've missed.

Comment: @thetaiko So I guess I'm wrong that PDO::query() isn't explicitly not recommended.  I have edited my answer to amend my error.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, that you have an error in your SQL query and line

```
$dbh->query('...')
```

returns false - according to [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php). Then you can't call method setFetchMode on `false`.

Enable throwing exceptions and it should help you:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```